# Android: Get logs continuously

Tags: java, android, process, logcat

How to get logs continuously from logcat?

I want to read logs on my own device. This service is actually intended to send sms when another application is stopped or uninstalled. If the log from logcat matched string like "Removing package com.package.name", sms will be sent.

Is there a function that I can call once to send logs continuously to my service.  If there is none, I'm thinking of running the code below every second:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat logcat -b events");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
Toast.makeText(LogReaderService.this, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: From where? your own device or someone elses?

Comment: @xBroak - question details updated to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I think that is  the only way that you can do it.

Don't put this into a production application doing that work every second will use up battery on the device.

Also be  aware that there is no  requirement that all devices send the same Log messages in the situations that you are interested in. It is very possible that there are devices out there that have either slightly  altered  log messages, or maybe even none at all. So if you intend to cover a wide range of devices you'll need to test on each and every one to make sure that they actually give you the Log outputs that you are looking for.

Comment: that's painful to know. my client wants to monitor if our app (tracker) is purposely stopped or uninstalled by the user. this is a corporate app that the management wants to run on personnel's phones continuously. is there a workaround? - @Tim